# SQL Table Data insertion

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am trying to enter data into my table, the column is of type `decimal`. When I enter `13.99`, it automatically rounds up to 14. How do I stop it from doing so?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[products] 
(
    [productsID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [price] DECIMAL(18) NOT NULL,
    [image] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([productsID] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Please supply code for the table schema and insert statement.

Comment: Also describe what you are looking at that makes you think the number has been rounded.

Comment: I am merely trying to insert data into the table, but once i press enter it rounds it up.

Comment: `DECIMAL(18,2)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data type is `Decimal(18)`.  According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql), you need to specify the number of decimal places you need;  e.g. `Decimal(18, 2)` for two decimal places.

The docs state that the second parameter (`s` or `scale`) is:

> The number of decimal digits that will be stored to the right of the decimal point...The default scale is 0;

Since you didn't have 'room' for the decimal places, they were taken off.

Comment: No problem...remember to accept the answer to your questions on this site!

Answer (score 1):

Decimal takes in two values, view their [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) to make sure you are passing in the right values to get the outcome you want.